# Trying out Proof By Induction for First time

Tags: proof-writing

I want to show that $(1-r)^x \ge (1-xr)\ \forall x \in \mathbb{N}, r \in \mathbb{R}, 0 \le r \le 1$

This is what I have so far, I'm hoping for a critique as well as help with the end since I don't think I'm quite there yet.

Base:

LHS =$(1-r)^1 = (1-r)$

RHS = $(1-1r) = (1-r)$

And the base case holds.

Hypothesis: Assume $(1-r)^k \ge (1-kr)$ is true for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$

Conclusion:
RHS = $1-(k+1)r$

LHS: 
\begin{align*}
(1-r)^{k+1}&=(1-r)^k(1-r)\\
& \ge (1-kr)(1-r) \quad \textrm{From Hypothesis}\\
&= 1-r-kr+kr^2\\
&= 1-kr-r+kr^2\\
&=1-(k+1)r+kr^2\\
\end{align*}

So, from here it seems clear to me that since $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and  $r^2$ is a perfect square, and therefore $\ge 0$, that my LHS $\ge$ RHS, and this would prove that it's true. But - I'm not sure that my reasoning is sound, or if I need to show more?

Edit to add: Is regular induction enough for this? Are there values that I haven't accounted for?

Comment: Yes it's correct;Nothing more to show

Comment: The proof is OK.  Two minor comments: (1) starting with $x=0$ is even simpler and gives you a stronger conclusion, namely that the inequality holds for all natural numbers, including $0$.  (2) $r^2$ is a square; *perfect* square is reserved for the squares of integers.

Comment: So, could it simply say $r^2$ is a square, therefore it is $\ge 0$?...Same idea as a perfect square except not an integer?